# How to debug Python import failure

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have a directory structure:

```
network/__init__.py
network/model.py
network/transformer/__init__.py
network/transformer/t_model.py
```

both `__init__.py` files have appropriate

```
__all__ = [
    "model",  # or "t_model" in the case of transformer
    "view",
    ]
```

In t_model.py, I have

```
from .. import model
```

but it says:

```
ImportError: cannot import name model
```

If I try

```
from ..model import Node
```

it says:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Node
```

These are very confusing errors.

---

Edit:  Even an absolute import fails:

```
import network as N
print(dir(N), N.__all__)
import network.model as M

['__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'transformer'] ['model', 'view']
Traceback (most recent call last):..........
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'model'
```

---

Edit: **It was a circular import**.

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: what python command line are you using to start your app?

Comment: The question "How to debug Python import failure?" was not answered... (although the specific problem has been solved)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me. Can you run/import model.py? If it has syntax errors you can't import it. (In general I recommend *not* to do relative imports, the use of them is limited).

Your absolute import is very confusing. The way to do an absolute import in this package is:

```
from network model import Node
```

This works fine.

I have a program.py in the top level (above network):

from network.transformer import t_model

And the t_model.py looks like this:

```
from .. import model
print "Model", model

from ..model import Node
print "Node", Node

from network.model import Node
print "Absolute", Node
```

And the output is:

```
Model <module 'network.model' from '/tmp/network/model.pyc'>
Node <class 'network.model.Node'>
Absolute <class 'network.model.Node'>
```

So as you can see it works fine your error is somewhere else.

Comment: If I do from network.model import Node, it says ImportError: cannot import name Node

Comment: @Neil G: Of course. As I showed above above your relative imports are correct, the error is somewhere else, not in how you write the import. Now if you read my answer, you'll see that I ask you a question. If you want help with this I suggest you answer it.

Comment: Importing model.py was the problem.  It turned out that model.py was importing t_model.py, which imported model.py.  I was almost pulling my hair out on this one.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Also, is it true that I should prefer absolute imports to relative ones?  Or vice versa?

Comment: @Neil G: Super! Glad to help! In my experience you almost never need relative imports, and absolute imports cause less confusion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918539/can-anyone-explain-pythons-relative-imports).

```
project/
    program.py           # entry point to the program
    network/         
        __init__.py
        transform/       # .. will target network
            __init__.py
```

I think you can also execute network/model.py from the directory below and get relative imports to network.  so...

```
network/
    model.py
    __init__.py
```

then you would start the program with `$ python network/model.py`.  You may or may not need to hit `__init__.py` instead.  I had an app engine program that targeted `module/__init__.py` and relative imports worked great.

Comment: Thanks.  I have `__init__.py` in every folder.