# ModuleNotFoundError in a local repository

Tags: python, linux, pythonpath

I have cloned a git repo, and it is now local on my machine.
Inside the path `Pipes/Filtering` there is a script called `filter_pileup_by_site_list.py` which I am trying to use, it's a docopt CLI so i'm going to the directory I have mentioned above and type the following in the terminal : `python filter_pileup_by_site_list.py Filter_pileup_by_site <parameters>`
The script imports a class from another directory in the repo which its path is: `Pipes/Utility`.
The command I have written above fails and returns the following error:

```
  File "filter_pileup_by_site_list.py", line 16, in <module>
    from Utility.Pileup_class import Pileup_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Utility'
```

All the solutions I came across were related to PYTHONPATH so I edited it, now when I type in the terminal `echo $PYTHONPATH` i get `/Pipes:/Pipes/Utility:/Pipes/Filtering:/Pipes/:/Bigdata/bioinf/Pipes3:/Bigdata/bioinf/Pipes:/Bigdata/users/eliran/Pipes`
And it still returns the exact backtrace I had before.

If it does matter somehow, I'm using linux mint.

Comment: Can you share the import statements for the script you’re trying to execute?

Comment: It appears in the backtrace.
There ```from Utility.Pileup_class import Pileup_line```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6134146/1216776

Comment: The script is working fine on a linux server, the import itself is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for:

add these lines at the top of the script:

```
import sys  
sys.path.insert(1, 'path/to/another/directory')
```

The following works because as default python looks for files only in the local folder so I had to add the above line to tell it to search in the previous folder so it can find `Utility` folder.