# Organizing project files and using global constants within modules

Tags: python, pygame

I am playing around with python (and pygame in particular), and I am organizing my project files:

```
/cls
    imageloader.py
    level.py
    __init__.py
/graphics
/maps
game.py
__init__.py
...
```

And comes the question about global constants in modules (like a configuration variables - FPS, TILESIZE, etc). Is there any way to access constant defined in game.py within /cls/level.py? And, what's more important - it's a wrong approach, isn't it? Should I pass it as an argument?

What's a pytonish way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the whole thing a package and also make `cls` a package (by providing `__init__.py` files in each directory), then from `levels.py` you can do `from ..game import someConstant`.

Comment: But if I do that - I get `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`

Comment: Did you use too many periods and/or forget `__init__.py` at the top level?

Comment: Just checked - I did not... However, for some reason `__init__.py` at top level is being ignored (compiled pyc is not created).

Comment: OK, this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918539/can-anyone-explain-pythons-relative-imports explains it (you might want to add a link to your answer).

Comment: The other approach besides what is suggested there is that in `game` you should do `from .cls import levels` instead of `from cls import levels`.