# Relative Imports in Django

Tags: django

I'm reading Two Scoops Django Best Practices to make my coding style improve. I'm in relative imports and here is the sample code to make it reusable.

```
Old Way:
from cones.foo import bar

New way:
from .foo import bar
```

The code above is for cones app, what if I call the other model in other app? Do I have to put like this:

```
from .foo import bar
from .other import sample

OR

from .foo import bar
from test.other import sample
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: There is a legitimate python module called "test" - don't call your modules that way to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I usually use imports like this only for one reason

```
from .foo import bar
from .other import sample
```

The reason being 
If Tomorrow, my module name changes from say 'test' to 'mytest' then the code does not require a refactoring. The code works without breaking.

### Update

All imports starting with a '.' dot, only works **within** that package.
Cross package imports need require the whole path.

Comment: You're right so that's the reason for refactoring, thanks for the info

Comment: Are you sure? Because it says here I can put double or more dots depends on the location of other files in other apps

Comment: '.' and '..' are known as intra-package references the name says it all. Only works within a module/package read.. read more [here] (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references). The examples given in for sub-modules not two different modules

Comment: What do you mean it only works within that module? Assuming you also refer to a module as simply a ```.py``` file then why would you import a function that is already in your current module (aka ```.py``` file).

Comment: @gmarais, yes what i wanted to mention was "with that  package",  I updated the answer. thank you

Answer (score 3):

If `test` is another app,

```
from .other import sample
```

wont work.

**Update:**

You can only use relative imports when you're importing from the same app.

Inside `test` app

```
from .other import sample
```

will work. But you'll still need the complete form

```
from cones.foo import bar
```

if you import method defined in `foo` from `test` app.

So answering your question the second way is the correct way.

Comment: what if I use like this to call in other folder from ...other import sample?

Comment: If that's the case what if I forgot where the file save? What's the good strategy for that?

Comment: Be careful with `from .. import`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918539/can-anyone-explain-pythons-relative-imports