# Proper way to set up PYTHONPATH for django project

Tags: python, django, pythonpath

In my file django app `tests.py`, I import another module I create called `helpers`. `helpers` is on the same directory level as `tests.py`. When I run `./manage.py tests` I get this error:

```
$ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
E
======================================================================
ERROR: api.tests (unittest.loader.ModuleImportFailure)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 58, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/case.py", line 577, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 32, in testFailure
    raise exception
ImportError: Failed to import test module: api.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 312, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 290, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/projects/cherngloong/cherngloong/api/tests.py", line 8, in <module>
    from helpers.APIHelpers import KeyGrabber
ImportError: No module named 'helpers'
```

Here is my project structure:

[image]

Basically, `tests.py` can't find the `helpers` module. I'm not sure what is the best/proper/standard way to avoid this problem within a django project

Comment: did you try from api.helpers.APIHelpers import KeyGrabber? Notice the name app first.

Comment: @jorlugaqui that worked! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
api.helpers.APIHelpers import KeyGrabber
```

in Django packages often start with the app name. You can also try [relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767426/relative-imports).