# ImportError: relative import with no known parent package - Importing a scripts from a directory "one level above" the current script's one

Tags: python, import

In my python script `L47_trial.py`, which has the following relative path with respect to my project:

```
my_scripts/04-trial/L47_trial.py
```

there is this import line

```
from ..starting_template import load_img
```

which should import the function `load_img` from the script `starting_template`, which has the following relative path with respect to my project:

```
my_scripts/starting_template.py
```

So, to be clear:

```
- my_scripts/
    - 04-trial/
        - L47_trial.py
    - starting_template.py
```

However, when I run

```
python my_scripts/04-trial/L47_trial.py
```

from my project directory (the folder one level upper with respect to `my_scripts`), I get this error:

```
from ..starting_template import load_img
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

My thinking is that as I run the file, python should do a relative import starting form the path of `my_scripts/04-trial/L47_trial.py`, so,
if `starting_template` were in the same directory of `L47_trial.py` (that is `04-trial/`), I would do

```
from starting_template import load_img
```

but since `starting_template` is one level upper, then I would expect

```
from ..starting_template import load_img
```

to work.

What is the problem with my import?

Is it forbidden in python to import a script "from directories one level above the current script's one"?

### What I tried

1. 

I tried to change

```
from ..starting_template import load_img
```

to

```
from my_scripts.starting_template import load_img
```

but I get

```
from my_scripts.resources.starting_template import load_img
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_scripts'
```

Why cannot it find `my_scripts` folder ?

2)

I tryed to move starting_template.py in the folder `my_scripts/resources/` and change

```
from ..starting_template import load_img
```

into

```
from my_scripts.resources.starting_template import load_img  # refactoring made by VScode
```

but I get again

```
from my_scripts.resources.starting_template import load_img
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_scripts'
```

### Notes

**Note**: I have tested that by moving `starting_template.py` into `my_scripts/S04-trial` and changing

```
from ..starting_template import load_img
```

to

```
from starting_template import load_img
```

solves the issue, but I would like to keep the file there where it is.

**Note**: The directories `my_scripts` and `my_scripts/S04-trial` contain a void file  `__init__.py`

Comment: You cannot use relative imports in scripts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: @mkrieger1 "You cannot use relative imports in scripts" do you mean it is only supported by frameworks such as Django, Flask, etc?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. That has nothing to do with frameworks. You can use relative imports in files that are imported as a module and part of a package, but not in files that are executed as a top-level script (i.e. by executing `python3 path/to/script.py`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood my bias.

I have developed the current project by replicating the import statements I made in a Django project:

```
- app_m/
    - algorithms/
        - handling.py
    - __init__.py
    - entity_relationship_models.py
```

Inside handling.py:

```
from app_m.entity_relationship_models import my_function
```

This line of import successfully run, and the structure of the Django project is the same of the one in my question:

```
app_m/                        --> my_scripts 
algorithms/                   --> 04_trial7
handlers.py                   --> L47_trial.py
entity_relationship_models.py --> starting_template.py
```

However, relative imports on Django work differently.

Django handles the relative import, while calling the scripts from command line as top-level scripts, does not support it.

As stated by @mkrieger:

> one can use relative imports in files that are imported as a module
> and part of a package, but not in files that are executed as a
> top-level script (i.e. by executing `python3 path/to/script.py`)

### Some information about relative imports in Django

I could not find a clear statement on Django official documentation, but it  seems that Django treats by default every app as a package, and that is the reason why in Django projects one can use relative imports, as it emerges from [this illuminating answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767508/7658051) on SO:

> You can only use relative imports when you're importing from the same
> app.

**Other useful resources I found:**

> Use absolute imports when necessary and prefer explicit relative
> imports for your local Django code.

from [a post](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-best-practices-imports) on learndjango.com

> when you’re running Django, your “current directory” is not the
> directory for each file being run - it’s the directory where you’re
> running manage.py. Relative imports are relative to that location, not
> the location of the function currently being executed.

from [a thread](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/relative-import-with-no-known-parent-package/8271/8) on djangoproject.com