# ValueError : attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have directory structure following :

```
/Test/
   /lib/
      lib1.py
   /main/
      main.py
```

and my `main.py` importing the class library which are defined in `lib1.py` using

```
from ..lib.lib1 import library
```

It gives this error:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

How can fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anyone explain python's relative imports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918539/can-anyone-explain-pythons-relative-imports)