# importing python module using relative name

Tags: python, python-import

I'm having difficultly with important a python module from another folder. Here's how my folder looks currently

```
foldername/
    __init__.py
    A/
        __init__.py
        spam.py
        grok.py
    B/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
```

I'm trying to import the functions and classes from the `grok.py` file into the `foo.py` in B. This is how my `foo.py` looks like

```
from ..A.spam import func
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Could somebody help me? I don't understand where I'm going wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918539/can-anyone-explain-pythons-relative-imports

Answer (score 0):

You can't use '..' like you do on the command line. You have to add your 'A' folder to your Python path. You can use `sys.path.append('/dir/of/A')` and then `from A.spam import func`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using sys.path you could also add a *.pth-file to your python or anaconda "site-packages"-folder which contains the path to the folder "A".
Import via `from A.spam import func` as @bikemule already proposed.